# Validar que una variable contenga letras y al menos un numero y un caracter especial en php

Tags: php, html

Necesito validar un input de contraseña para que e diga si se cumple o no la condicion

Hasta ahora llevo esto:

```
<?php
    include("con_db.php");
    $patron_texto = "/^[a-zA-Z!"#$%&/()=\s]+$/";
        $id = $_POST['id65'];
        if (strlen($_POST['contratxt']) >= 1){
            if(preg_match($patron_texto, $_POST['contratxt'])){
                $contra = $_POST['contratxt'];
                $consulta = "UPDATE usuarios SET contraseña = '$contra' WHERE id = '$id'";
                $resultado = mysqli_query($conex,$consulta);
                if ($resultado) {
                    echo "<script> alert('Nombre editado correctamente');</script>";
                }
                else {
                    echo "<script> alert('Error al editar.');</script>";
                }
            }
            else {
                echo "<script> alert('El nombre no esta en el formato correcto');</script>";
            }
        }
?>
```

Pero no se me ocurre como validar que sea uno o mas caracteres especiales o uno o mas numeros, ademas de letras.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una forma de hacer un validador muy sencillo puede ser en una función, primero calculando si la palabra tiene minúsculas (`$lowcase`), mayusculas (`$uppcase`), numeros (`$numbers`) y otro caracteres (`$special`).

Una vez ya se tiene la información anterior, entonces se pueden hacer las operaciones correspondientes si se cumplen las condiciones de presencia de ciertos caracteres.

En este caso construí una función genérica que puedes modificar y usar en otras implementaciones. Estoy usando un "**nivel**" de contraseña para variar la complejidad como tu quieras. Se colocó un `switch - case` donde se evalúa cada nivel. Nótese que los `case` no tienen `break`, por lo que apenas se cumple una condición, se evaluarán todos los niveles siguientes, excepto el `default` que se ejecuta si el nivel no es ninguno. Si todos los niveles posteriores se cumplen, la función retorna `true`, de lo contrario `false`.

```
<?php

function check_pcomplex($string, $minchar, $level) {
    /*$level = 1- Requerido al menos una letra de cualquier tipo o numeros, especiales son validos
      $level = 2- Lo del $level 1, pero con al menos una minuscula obligatoria
      $level = 3- Lo del $level 2, pero con al menos un numero obligatorio
      $level = 4- Lo del $level 3, pero con al menos una mayuscula, obligatoria
      $level = 5- Lo del $level 4, pero con al menos un caracter especial, obligatorio.*/
    $lowcase = preg_match('/[a-z]/', $string);
    $uppcase = preg_match('/[A-Z]/', $string);
    $numbers = preg_match('/\d/', $string);
    $special = preg_match('/[^a-zA-Z\d]/', $string);

    $passed = true;
    switch($level) {
        case 5: $passed = ($passed and $special);
        case 4: $passed = ($passed and $uppcase);
        case 3: $passed = ($passed and $numbers);
        case 2: $passed = ($passed and $lowcase);
        case 1: $passed = ($passed and ($lowcase or $uppcase or $numbers));
        case 0: $passed = ($passed and (strlen($string) >= $minchar)); 
        break;
        default: $passed = false;
    }
    return $passed;
}
```

[ Prueba ]

```
// Como usar: check_pcomplex('palabra', long_minima, nivel_de_complejidad)
var_dump(check_pcomplex('123456', 4, 1)); // true
var_dump(check_pcomplex('123456', 4, 2)); // false
var_dump(check_pcomplex('password', 8, 2)); // true
var_dump(check_pcomplex('password', 8, 3)); // false
var_dump(check_pcomplex('Password4', 8, 3)); // true
var_dump(check_pcomplex('Password4', 8, 4)); // true
var_dump(check_pcomplex('Passwords23', 8, 5)); // false
var_dump(check_pcomplex('Pa$$word$23', 8, 5)); // true
var_dump(check_pcomplex('Pa$$word$23', 12, 5)); // false
```

Answer (score 1):

La expresión regular podría ser así:

```
^(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[@$!%*#?&])[A-Za-z\d@$!%*#?&]{3,}$
```

Esta expresión validaría una cadena en caso de contener al menos una letra, un carácter especial y un número.

**Ejemplo:**

```
if (preg_match("/^(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[@$!%*#?&])[A-Za-z\d@$!%*#?&]{3,}$/", "11cont@rasenia1@")) {
    echo "La cadena contiene al menos un caracter especial, un número y una letra";
} 
else {
    echo "La cadena no cumple con el patrón: debe tener al menos un caracter especial, un número y una letra";
}
```